# Call function on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am quite new to javascript and jquery so this might be a really simple problem. Please don't mind.

I am appending new link(a) elements in division with id = "whatever" by

```
$("#whatever").append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', 'url').text('blah'));
```

And calling a function

```
$(function () {
  $('#whatever a').tagcloud();
});
```

on every link element inside that particular div.
But this function is being called only on old elements and not on the ones that I just dynamically added.
I tried doing this:

```
$(document).on("change", '#whatever', function () {
    $("whatever a").tagcloud();  
});
```

But its still not working.

Comment: And why not just wait until the elements are appended before you call the plugin ?

Comment: I am doing that only. First appending all the elements and then calling plugin.

Comment: If the method returns a jQuery object, what's wrong with `$("#whatever").append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', 'url').text('blah').tagcloud());` ?

Comment: @undefined - Not working :( It is not showing previous elements also.

Comment: What does `tagcloud()` method do? What about creating a demo on http://jsfiddle.net and reproducing the problem? So that people can suggest a _working_ way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=tcaJ048e53

Comment: Thanks. The fiddle is empty?

Comment: I just added my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42255/discussion-between-vikas-bansal-and-undefined)

Comment: Which tagCloud plugin are you using?  There are a bunch of different ones.

Comment: https://github.com/addywaddy/jquery.tagcloud.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it doesn't work as expected as you are missing adding `rel` attribute to the to-be-appended element(s).

```
// ...
// The plugin reads the rel attributes
var tagWeights = this.map(function(){
   return $(this).attr("rel");
});
```

Try this:

```
$('<a>').attr({'href': 'url', 'rel': 'value'})
        .text('blah')
        .tagcloud()
        .appendTo('#someWhere');
```

http://jsbin.com/uBAzItuj/3

Comment: Yes I just figured that out a minute ago. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $link = $('<a>').attr('href', 'url').text('blah');
$("#whatever").append($link);
$link.tagcloud();
```

`$(document).on("change"` will never fire.

Comment: Misprint, add `$link`

Comment: Because `innerHTML` or `appendChild` or any DOM manipulation didn't fire change event on document. Add [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24MRs/).

Comment: This is not working as well. It is not able to show old elements.

Answer (score 1):

A response to your edit, try this:

```
$(document).on("change", '#whatever', function () {
    $("#whatever a").tagcloud();  
});
```

I think you might have forgotten the # in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

First in your example `$("whatever a")` should be `$("#whatever a")` but also when I have this situation I delegate in the same action as the append

```
$("#whatever").append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', 'url').text('blah'));
$('#whatever a').off();
$('#whatever a').tagcloud();
```

Comment: Why remove all event handlers and then reinstall them all.  Why not do like Pinal's answer and just add event handlers to the newly created object.

Comment: the reason to remove old ones is because, if `#whatever` has multiple `<a>` elements, you will end up re-adding events to them causing them to trigger multiple times. Its not that I don't "like" the other answer, this is just a different way of doing it and how I tend to do it. Pinal adds it to each new element, I add it to all children of the parent the element is being appended to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").on("tagcloud", "#whatever", function(){
     $("#whatever").append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', 'url').text('blah')); 
});
```

Check this similar question out for more info:

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Also, jQuery has some info on it:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

I wanted to leave this as a comment, but couldn't. Hope it helps.

Comment: Check the edit. Also, if you are going to -1 something, its kind to leave a comment why. I added an example that I hope works and also provided documentation on this subject.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#whatever').on('change', 'a', function() {
     $(this).tagcloud();
 });
```

Comment: How can an anchor trigger change event?

Comment: Adding an anchor does not trigger a `.change()` event.