# jQuery: to call a function on dynamically inserted input elements

Tags: jquery, dom, input, dynamic, attributes

First of all I will make it clear, that I went through the below link and yet found it difficult to address my issue. 
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902413/call-custom-function-on-dynamically-created-elements-with-jquery), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305386/call-function-on-dynamically-added-elements)

***Issue:***

I have the below loaded on my page:

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <label class="someClassDifferentForEachLoadedElement btn btn-primary " 
        onclick="$('#someIdDifferentForEvryElement')
        .find('label.active')
        .toggleClass('active', false);
        $(this).toggleClass('active', true);">

  <input class="validated" style="display:none" toggle="true" toggle- 
         checkbox="false" type="radio" value="Y">
  Yes
 </label>     
 <label class="someClassDifferentForEachLoadedElement btn btn-primary"
        onclick="$('#someIdDifferentForEvryElement')
        .find('label.active')
        .toggleClass('active', false);
        $(this).toggleClass('active', true);">  

   <input class="validated" style="display:none" toggle="true" toggle- 
          checkbox="false" type="radio" value="N">
   No
  </label>
 </div>
```

All the above code (most complex code removed) displays a clickable Yes/No field as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y78C.jpg) image

The below element gets loaded dynamically on to DOM when answered **YES**

```
 <input class="validated GTnumeric" size="2" type="text" value="">
```

***Approach:***

Need to change the type of the loaded input element from text to tel.

I have the below for all elements loaded on to DOM which works great for elements loaded initially:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {                        
  $(".GTnumeric").not("[type=hidden]").attr("type", "tel");
 });
```

But I am finding it difficult to make it work for the dynamically loaded elements. I need to address the same issue on numerous [pages and I cannot target on any ID since it changes for every element.

Can anyone please help me solve this with a possible approach using jQuery. Appreciate your help.

***UPDATED:***

After some suggestion from @barmar and @f-CJ (Thanks to both of you), I have tried below:

I tried below:

```
 var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations)
               {
                 mutations.forEach(function (mutation)
                 {
                   console.log(mutation.type);

                 // here I need get all elements with class "GTnumeric" and 
                 // change its "type" to be "tel" if its not "hidden"

                 // **please help me out here**
                 // code mentioned below 

                 });
                });

 var config = {
 childList: true,
 subtree: true
 };

 // Node, config
var targetNode = document.body;
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

I am not sure how to refer the document again inside the for loop its throwing an error [Uncaught TypeError: t[i].getAttribute is not a function] when I try below:

**please help me out here**

```
     var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(".GTnumeric");
    for (var el in elems) {
        if (elems[el].getAttribute("type") != 'hidden') {
            elems[el].setAttribute("type", "tel");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where on the DOM is the `input` loaded?

Comment: @f-CJ it's loaded below the Yes/No element. Did I answer your question?

Comment: You need to run the code that changes the type after you load the elements dynamically.

Comment: None of the code you posted is relevant to this. Post the code that loads the new elements, and we can show you where this goes.

Comment: If you can modify the method that loads the `input`, it will be very easy. If you cannot modify the method that loads the `input`, we can offer different options to get what you want. Can you modify the method that loads the `input`?

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately I am not in a position to change that logic which loads the new element :(

Comment: @f-CJ No I cannot modify the method that loads input. I have to find a solution with the elements I have posted here.

Comment: You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes to the DOM automatically.

Comment: @Barmar sure will give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar I have updated what I have tried with MutationObserver please advice further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you cannot modify the method that loads the `input` file, I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Add a `click` event handler and periodically check until the new sibling element has been added -> modify it.

   ```
   $('div.btn-group > label').on('click', function(e) {        
       let $this = $(this);

       let interv = setInterval(function() {
           let gtNumeric = $this.siblings($(".GTnumeric").not("[type=hidden]")); 

           if (gtNumeric.length > 0) {
               gtNumeric.attr("type", "tel");
               clearInterval(interv);
           }
       }, 500);    
   });
   ```

The idea of the above script is to check siblings of the clicked `label` and check if there is one with the class `.GTnumeric`. Once it is found, change the `type` of the element and clear the interval. I put an interval of half a second (500), you can adapt it to your needs.

2. Use DOM Mutation Observer, you can check this [blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Comment: Could you please point me to any jsbin link or working example you have, for the first suggestion, it would help me understand better

Comment: @cheresdb not sure if I explained myself clear, any question?

Comment: Thanks for the example. There is one problem though, my element is not a sibling. The element gets inserted below the button, but not as a sibling, but as a new row element.

Comment: @cheresdb It gets added as a sibling of `div.btn-group`?

Comment: Nope. It gets added as a new div.row element. Is there a way I can refer the whole document when the click event occur to check if an element is added? That should solve the problem

Comment: @cheresdb Yes, with the DOM Mutation Oberserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I have tried something using Mutation Observer and stuck at some point. I will update my question. Please help me out there. Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions till now.